# Cannot pass data to getJSON even with closures

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, closures

I went through many solutions to this problem on SO and none of them work for me, unfortunately.

I want to dynamically load and place some elements on my page. HTML is generated by one of the scripts and the resulting template (for injecting data into it) is passed to getJSON method. I wanted to fill that template inside my callback method and then add it to the body.

The problem is getJSON function. I tried to pass panel value with closure and bind and none of them work.

```
init: function(panel) {


        // closure
        $.getJSON("scripts/getZones.php",
            (function () { // closure
                var p = panel;
                return function(zoneData) {
                    if (zoneData.status == true) {
                        $.each(zoneData.values, function(i, item) {
                            console.log("Module.Control_manual: Adding zone " + item.id);
// filling panel with data here - but panel is undefined
                        });
                    } else {
                        // error!
                        console.log("Module.Control_manual: Error: " + item['message']);
                    }
                }
            })
        );

    }
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Beside that you don't immediately invoke your `(function () { // closure .... })` function.  Your code does not show any part where try to use `panel` or `p` inside of your `function(zoneData)`.

Comment: You need to provide a working codes, at least a more complete ones, so people can reproduce your problem, without this, you'll leave us guessing, and none of us can give you the correct answer

Comment: why are you using a self-invoking function in you ajax request?

Comment: Beside that `zoneData` would be the problem in your current code: If `panel` is `undefined` at that place in you code then it is either already `undefined` before your `$.getJSON("scripts/getZones.php",` and you are doing something wrong when calling `init` or your set it to `undefined` somewhere in your `init` function. So first check what `console.dir(panel);` will show you right here : `init: function(panel) { console.dir(panel);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For closure,  You must execute your function, then the `getJSON` function could get the right callback function

```
init: function(panel) {


    // closure
    $.getJSON("scripts/getZones.php", 
        // closure, you must execute it first, then the `getJSON` function could get the right callback function
        (function() { 
            var p = panel;
            return function(zoneData) {
                if (zoneData.status == true) {
                    $.each(zoneData.values, function(i, item) {
                        console.log("Module.Control_manual: Adding zone " + item.id);

                    });
                } else {
                    // error!
                    console.log("Module.Control_manual: Error: " + item['message']);
                }
            }
        }());
    );

}
```

---

And further more, you should only do this closure way when you want to store the `panel`,otherwise you can just use panel instead the callback.

Comment: That was my problem - missing () for executing closure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

or yo can using bind method, to pass a parameter to callback function like this:

```
    function doAfterJson(panel){
                var p = panel;
                    return function(zoneData) {
                        if (zoneData.status == true) {
                            $.each(zoneData.values, function(i, item) {
                                console.log("Module.Control_manual: Adding zone " + item.id);
    // filling panel with data here - but panel is undefined
                            });
                        } else {
                            // error!
                            console.log("Module.Control_manual: Error: " + item['message']);
                        }
                    }
                }

    }

    //use 'bind(scope,parameter)' to pass scope and parameter to callback function

init: function(panel) {


        // closure
        $.getJSON("scripts/getZones.php",doAfterJson.bind(this,panel));
    }
```